# Move files from list into directory named after list file

Tags: linux, bash

I've had a look through stackflow and it seems this question is asked quite alot but it doesn't quite answer my question.

I have 4 text files named `1.txt` to `4.txt` and 4 directories named `1` to `4`. Within each `txt` file is a list of file names:

```
==> 1.txt <==
A.fa
B.fa
C.fa


==> 2.txt <==
D.fa
E.fa
F.fa

==> 3.txt <==
G.fa
H.fa
I.fa


==> 4.txt <==
J.fa
H.fa
L.fa
```

The `fa` files and `txt` files are in the same directory as the 4 subdirectories.

I want to move the `fa` files listed in the `txt` files into the directories named after the file they are listed in.

So `A.fa B.fa C.fa` moved to `1`, etc.

I have tried this:

```
for file in *.txt; do 
    basename=${file%.txt}
         while IFS= read -r file; do 
         mv -v "$file" "$basename/$file"
    done
done
```

It seems to stall and not do anything so I quit the command. I have a feeling that my issue is with `$basename` and maybe linux wont recognize `$basename` as a directory name.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `while IFS= read -r file; do` is not reading from anything (ie. it's reading from standard input). Actually read from the file `while IFS= read -r file; do... done <"$file"`

Comment: thanks, that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to redirect input of the `while read` loop from the file containing the list of filenames.

Also, you're using the same variable `file` in the main `for` loop and the inner `read`.

```
for file in *.txt; do 
    basename=${file%.txt}
    while IFS= read -r innerfile; do 
        mv -v "$innerfile" "$basename/$innerfile"
    done < "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the following Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne '( $dir = $ARGV ) =~ s{.txt}{}; $cmd = "mv $_ $dir"; print $cmd; system $cmd and die $?;' [1-4].txt
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`$ARGV` : current file name.

**SEE ALSO:**

[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)